# PHP Wordpress Plugin - Function Output is oke but when updating database its not oke.

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

```
$datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$timeout = 10;
$redirect = 10;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fivesdraft->url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36");
curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, $redirect);
curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING, " ");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);

$http_respond = curl_exec($ch);
$http_respond = trim(strip_tags($http_respond));
$http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$redirectURL = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL);

  echo '$fivesdraft->url';
  echo '$http_code';
  echo '$redirectURL';

curl_close($ch);
```

With the above code there is no problem when i echo the response.
but when i change the echo part with :

```
global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->update( 
        'tp_backlinks', 
            array( 
                'last_checkd' => $datetime, 
                'last_status' => $http_code,
                'last_redirect' => $redirectURL
            ), 
            array( 'ID' => $fivesdraft->ID ), 
                array( 
                    '%s',
                    '%d',
                    '%s' 
                ), 
            array( '%d' ) 
    );
```

most of my website's give a status code 400 or 0
What am i doing wrong here.

Comment: check the return value from $wpdb->update; if it `=== false ` you had a SQL error of some sort. Any chance `last_checkd` should be `last_checked`?

Comment: i have changed ' $wpdb->update( ' to ' $test = $wpdb->update( ' and added 'if ($test === false) if ($test === 0) if ($test > 0) ' but i get nothing returnd

Answer (score 0):

I found The problem,

I was forgetting to Trim my URL.

```
$url = trim($fivesdraft->url);
```

Now it works fine